# how to get the device(android) tel number or other device unique id which can be taken from the system

Tags: android

I want to enter an website using the tel num as a password how do i get it using the android API is it possible ?

---

or is there another key value on the android which is unique and I can ask him from the android system , android devices and therefore security is promised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a unique ID you can use the ANDROID_ID. It is unique for a device:

```
String id = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

(context could be your Activity or otherwise)

You probably shouldn't send this ID out unchanged; it would be better to do a hash on it first.

Comment: To be precise: Add an application-specific suffix to the `id` you'd get with the method above, and hash the combined string. Such a sffuix is called a salt.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's not possible due security reasons. 
For example, some apps which really need your number like Skype lite ask user to enter it manually.